how to merge lists of multiple Data Frames and decreasing the second lists of dataframes?
I have lists of datframes.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"Name":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"Age":[30,31,32,33],"Mobile":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"Name":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"Age":[30,31,32,33],"Mobile":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"Name":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"Age":[30,31,32,33],"Mobile":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])

df4 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"ename":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"pg":[30,31,32,33],"M+":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])
df5 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"en":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"pg+":[30,31,32,33],"Tm":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])
df6 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"years":["2016","2018","2019",""],"lev":[30,31,32,33],"d+":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])

data_frames1 = [df1,df2,df3]
data_frames2 = [df4,df5,df6]

I have tried with below code but not worked.
check1 = []
test = []
for i in range(len(data_frames1)):
    for j in range(len(data_frames2)):
        # merge_dfs = pd.merge(data_frames1[i],data_frames2[j],on="Id",how="left")
        if len(test) <= 0:
            test.append(data_frames1[i])
        else:
            fin = test[-1].merge(data_frames2[j],how='left',on='Id')
            test.append(fin)

My Expecting out put is.
I want to merge datframes like below.
m1 = df1.merge(df4,how="left",on="Id")
m2 = m1.merge(df5,how="left",on="Id")
m3 = m2.merge(df6,how="left",on="Id") -> This is my one final df

and next should merge like..
m4 = df2.merge(df5,how="left",on="Id")
m5 = m4.merge(df6,how="left",on="Id") -> This is my second final df

and third is
m6 = df3.merge(df6,how="left",on="Id") -> This my third final df

I want generate dataframes like above using for loops.
can anyone help me how to do this using any logics...

IIUC, you could use functools.reduce, slicing and a loop:
from functools import reduce

assert len(data_frames1) == len(data_frames2)

out = [
    reduce(
        lambda a, b: a.merge(b, how='left', on='Id'),
        data_frames2[i:],
        data_frames1[i],
    )
    for i in range(len(data_frames1))
]

# checking the output is as expected
# all(a.equals(b) for a,b in zip(out, [m3, m5, m6]))
# True

Output:
[    Id    Name  Age  Mobile   ename  pg  M+      en  pg+  Tm years  lev  d+
0  101  Harish   30       1  Harish  30   1  Harish   30   1  2016   30   1
1  102    Hari   31       2    Hari  31   2    Hari   31   2  2018   31   2
2  103   Harry   32       3   Harry  32   3   Harry   32   3  2019   32   3
3  104           33       3          33   3           33   3         33   3,
    Id    Name  Age  Mobile      en  pg+  Tm years  lev  d+
0  101  Harish   30       1  Harish   30   1  2016   30   1
1  102    Hari   31       2    Hari   31   2  2018   31   2
2  103   Harry   32       3   Harry   32   3  2019   32   3
3  104           33       3           33   3         33   3,
    Id    Name  Age  Mobile years  lev  d+
0  101  Harish   30       1  2016   30   1
1  102    Hari   31       2  2018   31   2
2  103   Harry   32       3  2019   32   3
3  104           33       3         33   3]


You can use slicing dynamically based on the index i of the data_frames1 list.
final_dfs = []

for i, df in enumerate(data_frames1):
    merged_df = df.copy()  # Avoid modifying the original DataFrame
    merge_dfs = data_frames2[i:]
    
    for merge_df in merge_dfs:
        merged_df = merged_df.merge(merge_df, how="left", on="Id")
    
    final_dfs.append(merged_df)

Output:
[    Id    Name  Age  Mobile   ename  pg  M+      en  pg+  Tm years  lev  d+
 0  101  Harish   30       1  Harish  30   1  Harish   30   1  2016   30   1
 1  102    Hari   31       2    Hari  31   2    Hari   31   2  2018   31   2
 2  103   Harry   32       3   Harry  32   3   Harry   32   3  2019   32   3
 3  104           33       3          33   3           33   3         33   3,
     Id    Name  Age  Mobile      en  pg+  Tm years  lev  d+
 0  101  Harish   30       1  Harish   30   1  2016   30   1
 1  102    Hari   31       2    Hari   31   2  2018   31   2
 2  103   Harry   32       3   Harry   32   3  2019   32   3
 3  104           33       3           33   3         33   3,
     Id    Name  Age  Mobile years  lev  d+
 0  101  Harish   30       1  2016   30   1
 1  102    Hari   31       2  2018   31   2
 2  103   Harry   32       3  2019   32   3
 3  104           33       3         33   3]


Since you’re joining across multiple dataframes at once for many of these operations
you can also set the index to the join column for each dataframe you’re working with
and then use pandas.concat:
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"Name":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"Age":[30,31,32,33],"Mobile":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"Name":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"Age":[30,31,32,33],"Mobile":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"Name":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"Age":[30,31,32,33],"Mobile":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])

df4 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"ename":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"pg":[30,31,32,33],"M+":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])
df5 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"en":["Harish","Hari","Harry",""],"pg+":[30,31,32,33],"Tm":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])
df6 = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[101,102,103,104],"years":["2016","2018","2019",""],"lev":[30,31,32,33],"d+":[1,2,3,3]},index=[0,1,2,3])

data_frames1 = [df1,df2,df3]
data_frames2 = [df4,df5,df6]

# set index of all frames to the column to join on
data_frames1 = [df.set_index('Id') for df in data_frames1]
data_frames2 = [df.set_index('Id') for df in data_frames2]

# concatenate each df from data_frames1 to the subset of data_frames2
# could also be done as a list comprehension.
results = []
for i, df in enumerate(data_frames1):
    results.append(
        pd.concat([df, *data_frames2[i:]], axis=1, join='inner')
    )

print(*results, sep='\n' * 2)
#        Name  Age  Mobile   ename  pg  M+      en  pg+  Tm years  lev  d+
# Id
# 101  Harish   30       1  Harish  30   1  Harish   30   1  2016   30   1
# 102    Hari   31       2    Hari  31   2    Hari   31   2  2018   31   2
# 103   Harry   32       3   Harry  32   3   Harry   32   3  2019   32   3
# 104           33       3          33   3           33   3         33   3

#        Name  Age  Mobile      en  pg+  Tm years  lev  d+
# Id
# 101  Harish   30       1  Harish   30   1  2016   30   1
# 102    Hari   31       2    Hari   31   2  2018   31   2
# 103   Harry   32       3   Harry   32   3  2019   32   3
# 104           33       3           33   3         33   3

#        Name  Age  Mobile years  lev  d+
# Id
# 101  Harish   30       1  2016   30   1
# 102    Hari   31       2  2018   31   2
# 103   Harry   32       3  2019   32   3
# 104           33       3         33   3

